# How to split a php string

Tags: php, variables, echo

Stack Overflow-ers,

I can output the variable `$raw_date` as 20130216 by simply using `echo $raw_date;`, however I would like to be able to output either 16/02 or 16/02/2013 from the same `$raw_date` variable.

Is this possible, and if so how?

Thanks,
Jamie

Comment: Yes it is. what have you tried?

Comment: string splitting isn't the answer you want; you don't have to do date formatting manually -- PHP has much more powerful tools available for you. If you must do it manually (or for other similar tasks), look up the `str_split()` function, but with such an obvious function name to look for, I'm a bit worried that you didn't manage to find it without asking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $raw_data);
echo $d->format('d/m/Y');
```

Comment: +1 for a *really good* answer (instead of boring old `substr()`)

Comment: +1 for giving him what he actually needs, rather than what he asked for.

Comment: Spudley, you couldn't be more right, it's exactly what I need, I was searching for the wrong thing; thank you very much!